# It's possible play sound in an inactive chrome tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

We have developed a webchat app that notifies the user if the message was received with firebase notification library, but we are totaly unable to play any sound when the notification arrives, that aparently is happenning due to a chrome performance algorithm

But we notice whatsapp webapp is able to do that, so, does anyone knows how to play a short notification audio when chrome tab is not focused?

Comment: If your goal is to send notifications, then maybe just use the [Notifications API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API)?

Comment: Most clients won't allow this.

Comment: Is there no sound at all? Or will it play once you make the tab active again? Does the console show any errors? I know that browser often don't allow sound to be played unless there has been an interaction with the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use a JavaScript Webworker https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Basically a Webworker is like a Backgroundtask. So your Tab doesn‘t need to focused to play the sound. Maybe that helps

Comment: it's possible play sound by a webworker or just audio processing?