# Sound won't played untill switch tab

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to play a simple audio when user opens a tab in my web application,

the audio file works fine when the user left click and open a new tab,

However, when the user do a control click or right click, opens an inactive tab, the sound will not be played until the user switch to that tab

I have tried to load the audio [when page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33196475/playing-sound-from-inactive-browser-tab) but seems not working

I tried to use the [webworker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72201313/its-possible-play-sound-in-an-inactive-chrome-tab), but it has limited documentation in Typescipt

I'm wondering are there any workaround for this issue, so that the audio files can be played even when the user is not visiting that tab (inactive tabs)